Star wars 25th anniversary
I have a Lego Star wars 25th anniversary set but I don't know which one it is. Can someone help identify it. There are 6 bags

Hi Ryan and welcome to Bricks.SE! There are quite many sets in that product line, so please help us help you and either post some photos of the bags or check the link Henrik posted above and let us know where you have troubles following that guide. Play well!
